# Calling same API multiple Times

Tags: api, loops, while-loop

Is it possible to give a sample of calling the same API multiple times with different parameters?
So let's say I call 1 API where the parameters give you page 1 with 200 records. how do I call the same API multiple times with different parameters each time? and how would I go about putting a few second pauses after 10 API calls and start the next 10 API calls so on so forth?

is it possible to show it in Javascript: its just so that I have a starting point on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem above:

```
function rowcount()
{ 
  var token = getAccessToken();
  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  
   
   while (go) {
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) {
       go = false; 
    }
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
      i++;
   
      Logger.log(rows)
      }
      return rows
   }
  
  
function repeatloop()
{
  let counter = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i <= 93; i++)
      {
        {
        Utilities.sleep(10000);
        Logger.log(i);

        counter += rowcount();
        Logger.log("Total count "+ counter);
        }
        
      }
       return counter; 
  }
```